# how to get rid of vertical scroller

Tags: html, css

In my website vertical scroll appears when I change the height, how is possible :

My html is following :

```
<html>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper"> 
 <section>
 <section class="tall-section">
 </section>
 <section>
 </div> 
<body>
</html>
```

Css :

```
.tall-section{
height:1100px !Important;
}
```

This is when it appears.

However if I remove `tall-section` there is no vertical scroller and the css takes the old height set previously with `#wrapper > section > section` which is `763px`.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-height`. This would allow the div to expand if there's more content than what fits into 1100px.

Comment: @London: In that case I do not understand your problem. Please make a reproducible test case on http://jsfiddle.net or http://dabblet.com

Answer (score 0):

The scroller you see is for outer  that has fixed height. Do not wrap your new section with another section, or use the solution above.